# change background color in core.scss:149

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I want to change the complete background color of my ionic page, in my scenario, it's the login page. when I check the code in Chrome developer tools, is see the core.scss:149. when I add there some custom CSS like :  `background-color: red` what I want works. but where I access this CSS in line in my code. when I add some custom CSS in the SCSS file from my component it doesn't work. How do I achieve this success? [image]

I just want to change the background color of my login component html page, via the SCSS file.

my CSS looks like this:

```
.div-login{
    min-height: 70%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    min-width: 60%;
    background-color: gray;
}

.ion-page {
    background-color: red !important;
}

.loginFields{  
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;  
}
```

my HTML looks like this :

```
<div class="div-login">
   <div *ngIf="!registerNewUserVariable">
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
         <p style="font-size: 20px;">Login</p>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
      </div>
      <div>
         <form (ngSubmit)="login()" [formGroup]="credentials">
         <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom" class="loginFields">
            <ion-input
               type="email"
               placeholder="Email "
               formControlName="email"
               ></ion-input>
         </ion-item>
         <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom" class="loginFields">
            <ion-input
               type="password"
               placeholder=""
               formControlName="password"
               ></ion-input>
         </ion-item>
         </form>
         <p (click)="resetPassword_()" style="font-size: 12px; text-decoration: underline; margin-left: 7%;">Passwort vergessen</p>
      </div>
      <ion-button type="submit" color="warning" class="loginFields" expand="block" [disabled]="!credentials.valid" (click)="login()" style="margin-top: 15%;"> Sign in</ion-button>
      <p style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;"> connect </p>
      <ion-button color="light" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; margin-top: 10%;" (click)="loginWithGoogle()">
         <ion-icon name="logo-google"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <!--     <p style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: center;"> No Email Account?  <br> <u> Okay Lets Goooo  </u> </p> -->
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
         <p  (click)="registerNewUser()" style="font-size: 12px; white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: center;">No Email Account?  <br> <b> <u>Okay Lets Goooo</u>  </b>  </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="registerNewUserVariable">
      <ion-button (click)="registerNewUser()" style="margin-top: 5%; margin-left: 5%;" color="medium">
         <ion-icon name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
         <p style="font-size: 20px; white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: center;">nice to meet u </p>
      </div>
      <p style="margin-left: 5%;">Email? </p>
      <form (ngSubmit)="register()" [formGroup]="credentialsRegister">
      <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom" class="loginFields">
         <ion-input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email "
            formControlName="email_"
            ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <p style="margin-left: 5%;"> pw</p>
      <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom" class="loginFields">
         <ion-input
            type="password"
            placeholder=""
            formControlName="password_"
            ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom" class="loginFields">
         <ion-input
            type="password"
            placeholder=" check"
            formControlName="passwordCheck_"
            ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      </form>
      <ion-button type="submit" color="warning" class="loginFields" expand="block" (click)="register()" style="margin-top: 15%;"> Register</ion-button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add !important to your background-color statement like this

```
.div-background {
background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: i tried this before it dont work :(

Comment: can you please share your css your editor?

Comment: sure i added those code

Comment: check this code in your css ,.add background color to this class check th